# add_filter in Wordpress, how do I know if it is run?

Tags: php, wordpress, debugging

I am trying to add a search box to the main menu in Wordpress. According to some posts on the net it could be done something like this:

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items','menu_search');
function menu_search($items){
  $search = '<li class="search">';
  $search .= '<form method="get" id="searchform" action="/">';
  $search .= '<input type="text" class="field" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Search" />';
  $search .= '</form>';
  $search .= '</li>';
  return $items . $search;
}
```

It does not work for some reason, there is no search box in the menus. I am unused to PHP and debugging of PHP so I just installed the plugin Debug This. It shows me the function menu_search above was indeed on wp_nav_menu_items.

How can I dig into this?

UPDATE: I used Debug Bar+Debug My Plugin. They seem to be very good tools. So I found the problem: The menus were not where WP expected. So this filter was not run. In fact the menus were setup by wp_page_menu. So now I will try to understand why and what that means. ;-)

Comment: Have you checked this hasn't been added but isn't being displayed? Viewing the source? Where is this code? Inside functions.php? Finally I'd suggest adding a check so it only shows on one menu and not all but we can go into that once we know why it's not working.

Comment: Thanks @NathanDawson. Yes, I can't find any trace of it in the html source. Yes, in functions.php in my theme. Trying to trace it with Debug Bar/My Plugin, but can't get any output there. Things are not running smoothly tonight. ;-)

Comment: Hardcore debug: `var_dump($items); die();`. Mediumcore, doesn't always work, `echo '<pre>'.print_r($items,true).'</pre>';`. Softcore, search for FirePHP.

Comment: Softcore seems better. In fact the tools I did find are rather cool. How do they compare to FirePHP?

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/145/how-do-you-debug-plugins

Comment: Thanks @brasofilo, lots of suggestions there. I see that xdebug gives backtraces. Is that still the way to get them?

Comment: yes this is display but search not work so just change your action form i havedefine in bellow code.

Comment: you can said this is work? but this one work after some changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did a complete answer on WPSE for everyone to go and have a look at. Hope this will help everyone on stackoverflow.

[Debugging - trying to add search box to menus](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/138712/31545)

Answer (score 1):

1. Add this code in function.php.
2. This is display on your header menu.

> ```
> add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items','menu_search');
> function menu_search($items){
>   $search = '<li class="search">';
>   $search .= '<form method="get" id="searchform" action="'.site_url().'/">';
>   $search .= '<input type="text" class="field" name="s" value="'.get_search_query().'" id="s" placeholder="Search" />';
>   $search .= '</form>';
>   $search .= '</li>';
>   return $items . $search;
> }
> ```

[More info](http://cmsblogheart.wordpress.com/2014/03/19/search-box-on-navigation-menu/)

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty way is to call **error_log()** inside the 'hooked' function, like so:

```
add_filter("the_filter_name", "the_function_name", 10, 4);

function the_function_name($p1, $p2, $p3, $p4)
{
   error_log(__FUNCTION__ . "\n", 3, "/tmp/plugin.log");
}
```

*You could wrap the error_log with some timestamp info and newline char.*

```
// simple debug function
function plugin_debug($msg)
{
    error_log( $msg . "\n", 3, "/tmp/plugin.log");
}
```